# Flutter bounded height not working in container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I want to show icons from the asset file. I give a specific height on my container on the notification card, Want to warp within this height but the icon shows bigger than my given height.
Here below I attached my getting output and my expected output picture,

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

My Code:

```
Container(
    height: 48,
    width: 48,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: whiteColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    child: Container(
        height: 24,
        width: 24,
        child: Image.asset("assets/icons/bell.png"))))
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem behind it And how can I solve it?

Comment: wrap Image.asset in padding

Comment: instead of making the container child of another, use stack.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the reason is - those two widgets have different parent widgets, and the size of child widget is calculated according to parent widget.

You can try to use TextField with PrefixIcon and SuffixIcon/ and play around with it.

Here is some material of how to use it:

[Youtube Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWa6iGncZ5Q)

It's always better not to make a wheels by yourself, try to use TextField with prebuilt options.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helps to you and just replace my image name with your image name and I used TextFormField also

```
      Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 48,
                    width: 350,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                      //color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'What You are Lokking For',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/1.png",
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Result screen like [image]